# Joining two pandas dataframes are failing

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes that look like this:

`df_out`:

```
Prediction       count_human  count_bot  %_bot_tweets
username
666STEVEROGERS             8        131      0.942446
ADELE_BROCK                0        126      1.000000
ADRIANAMFTTT              99          0      0.000000
AHMADRADJAB                0        108      1.000000
ALBERTA_HAYNESS          101          0      0.000000
ALTMANBELINDA              0        139      1.000000
ALVA_MC_GHEE              29        104      0.781955
ANGELITHSS                 0        113      1.000000
ANN1EMCCONNELL             0        125      1.000000
ANWARJAMIL22               0        112      1.000000
AN_N_GASTON                0        107      1.000000
ARONHOLDEN8               89         31      0.258333
ARTHCLAUDIA                0        103      1.000000
ASSUNCAOWALLAS             0        108      1.000000
BECCYWILL                  0        132      1.000000
BELOZEROVNIKIT           132          8      0.057143
BEN_SAR_GENT              24         84      0.777778
BERT_HENLEY              105          0      0.000000
BISHOLORINE                0        117      1.000000
BLACKERTHEBERR5            4        100      0.961538
BLACKTIVISTSUS            49         68      0.581197
BLACK_ELEVATION           32         74      0.698113
BOGDANOVAO2                0        127      1.000000
BREMENBOTE                70         39      0.357798
B_stever96                 0        171      1.000000
CALIFRONIAREP             60         72      0.545455
C_dos_94                   0        121      1.000000
Cassidygirly               0        153      1.000000
ChuckSpeaks_               0        185      1.000000
Cyabooty                 111          0      0.000000
DurkinSays                 0        131      1.000000
LSU_studyabroad          117          0      0.000000
MisMonWEXP               131          0      0.000000
NextLevel_Mel              0        185      1.000000
PeterDuca                108          0      0.000000
ShellMarcel                0         97      1.000000
Sir_Fried_Alott            0        144      1.000000
XavierRivera_            197          0      0.000000
ZacharyFlair             213          0      0.000000
brentvarney44              0        126      1.000000
cbars68                  225          0      0.000000
chloeschultz11             0        106      1.000000
hoang_le_96                0        104      1.000000
kdougherty178              0        127      1.000000
lasallephilo             138          0      0.000000
lovely_cunt_               0        137      1.000000
megliebsch                 0        217      1.000000
msimps_15                138          0      0.000000
okweightlossdna          105          0      0.000000
tankthe_hank             231          0      0.000000
```

And `knn_res`:

```
      following  followers        username  Prediction  is_bot
0           199         77      megliebsch           1       0
1           199         77      megliebsch           1       0
2           199         77      megliebsch           1       0
3           199         77      megliebsch           1       0
4           199         77      megliebsch           1       0
...         ...        ...             ...         ...     ...
6643         67         57  ASSUNCAOWALLAS           1       1
6644         67         57  ASSUNCAOWALLAS           1       1
6645         67         57  ASSUNCAOWALLAS           1       1
6646         67         57  ASSUNCAOWALLAS           1       1
6647         67         57  ASSUNCAOWALLAS           1       1
```

What I am trying to do is, for each `username` in `df_out`, left join to `knn_res` to get the `following` and `followers` values.

In SQL, I could do this with:
`SELECT a.*, b.following, b.followers FROM df_out a LEFT JOIN knn_res b ON a.username = b.username`

I have tried:

```
test_df = df_out
test_df.set_index('username').join(knn_res.set_index('username'), on='username', how='left')
print(test_df)
```

Which yielded:

```
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4396, in set_index
    raise KeyError("None of {} are in the columns".format(missing))
KeyError: "None of ['username'] are in the columns"
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried to reference [this documentation for the problem](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

**UPDATE**

I also tried `inner join`, which yielded the exact same results:

```
  File "C:\Python367-64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4396, in set_index
    raise KeyError("None of {} are in the columns".format(missing))
KeyError: "None of ['username'] are in the columns"
```

`df_out` is created with:

```
df_out = (knn_res.groupby(['username', 'Prediction']).is_bot.count().unstack(fill_value=0).
             rename({0: 'count_human', 1: 'count_bot'}, axis= 1))

df_out['%_bot_tweets'] = df_out['count_bot'] / (df_out['count_bot'] + df_out['count_human'])
```

Comment: Can you check both DataFrames actually have a column called 'username'? How are you generating df_out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Default `join` option is `left`, so you don't need specify it. Both dataframes have `username` as index and `join` works on index, so you also don't need specifying `on` option. Lastly, you want to join only columns `following` and `followers`, so after set `username` as index, just slice those 2 columns for joining. (*Note: you should use `copy()` when you want to copy original dataframe to a `test_df` because without `copy()`, both point to the same dataframe object*)

```
test_df = df_out.copy()
test_df = test_df.join(knn_res.set_index('username')[['following', 'followers']])
print(test_df)

Out[93]:
                 count_human  count_bot  %_bot_tweets  following  followers
username
666STEVEROGERS             8        131      0.942446        NaN        NaN
ADELE_BROCK                0        126      1.000000        NaN        NaN
ADRIANAMFTTT              99          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
AHMADRADJAB                0        108      1.000000        NaN        NaN
ALBERTA_HAYNESS          101          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
ALTMANBELINDA              0        139      1.000000        NaN        NaN
ALVA_MC_GHEE              29        104      0.781955        NaN        NaN
ANGELITHSS                 0        113      1.000000        NaN        NaN
ANN1EMCCONNELL             0        125      1.000000        NaN        NaN
ANWARJAMIL22               0        112      1.000000        NaN        NaN
AN_N_GASTON                0        107      1.000000        NaN        NaN
ARONHOLDEN8               89         31      0.258333        NaN        NaN
ARTHCLAUDIA                0        103      1.000000        NaN        NaN
ASSUNCAOWALLAS             0        108      1.000000       67.0       57.0
ASSUNCAOWALLAS             0        108      1.000000       67.0       57.0
ASSUNCAOWALLAS             0        108      1.000000       67.0       57.0
ASSUNCAOWALLAS             0        108      1.000000       67.0       57.0
ASSUNCAOWALLAS             0        108      1.000000       67.0       57.0
BECCYWILL                  0        132      1.000000        NaN        NaN
BELOZEROVNIKIT           132          8      0.057143        NaN        NaN
BEN_SAR_GENT              24         84      0.777778        NaN        NaN
BERT_HENLEY              105          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
BISHOLORINE                0        117      1.000000        NaN        NaN
BLACKERTHEBERR5            4        100      0.961538        NaN        NaN
BLACKTIVISTSUS            49         68      0.581197        NaN        NaN
BLACK_ELEVATION           32         74      0.698113        NaN        NaN
BOGDANOVAO2                0        127      1.000000        NaN        NaN
BREMENBOTE                70         39      0.357798        NaN        NaN
B_stever96                 0        171      1.000000        NaN        NaN
CALIFRONIAREP             60         72      0.545455        NaN        NaN
C_dos_94                   0        121      1.000000        NaN        NaN
Cassidygirly               0        153      1.000000        NaN        NaN
ChuckSpeaks_               0        185      1.000000        NaN        NaN
Cyabooty                 111          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
DurkinSays                 0        131      1.000000        NaN        NaN
LSU_studyabroad          117          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
MisMonWEXP               131          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
NextLevel_Mel              0        185      1.000000        NaN        NaN
PeterDuca                108          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
ShellMarcel                0         97      1.000000        NaN        NaN
Sir_Fried_Alott            0        144      1.000000        NaN        NaN
XavierRivera_            197          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
ZacharyFlair             213          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
brentvarney44              0        126      1.000000        NaN        NaN
cbars68                  225          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
chloeschultz11             0        106      1.000000        NaN        NaN
hoang_le_96                0        104      1.000000        NaN        NaN
kdougherty178              0        127      1.000000        NaN        NaN
lasallephilo             138          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
lovely_cunt_               0        137      1.000000        NaN        NaN
megliebsch                 0        217      1.000000      199.0       77.0
megliebsch                 0        217      1.000000      199.0       77.0
megliebsch                 0        217      1.000000      199.0       77.0
megliebsch                 0        217      1.000000      199.0       77.0
megliebsch                 0        217      1.000000      199.0       77.0
msimps_15                138          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
okweightlossdna          105          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
tankthe_hank             231          0      0.000000        NaN        NaN
```

Comment: BTW - You forgot closing parenthesis on `test_df = test_df.join(knn_res.set_index('username')[['following', 'followers']]` :)

Comment: @JerryM.: sharp eyes! yes, I miscopied it :)